# how to make div's move to the middle according to screen widths-responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to create a website template and I have 3 divs that I have sized equally and when I edit it on codepen using my laptop, it looks perfectly centered, but when I use my monitor( which is a much larger screen) the divs all shift to one side. How do I make my divs responsive to a change in screen widths. In this case, I want my divs to all come together in the middle of the page if the screen is wide, but if it is a laptop screen I want the div's to fill the space.

Here is a codepen to show you what it looks like now: https://codepen.io/chenius/pen/eKvRKp/

snippet of code for one of the divs:

```
.post1{
position: absolute;
width: 392px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #F1F0F0;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a codepen try to include your problem only. I've update your codepen.
If you try to make a responsive design don't use `px` as a size. If you try to style all blocks with position absolute you don't have controll in your CSS.

Try using `display: flex` combined with a `%` width and maybe a max-width depending on your style preferences

```css
#bodyposts {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
.post { 
  width: calc(100% / 3); 
  max-width: 368px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyposts">
  <div class="post1 post">
    <img src="https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AACOIvsj9S-Od_SOp3CrZNZD9a2-vgB9txeSuP95IDvWhA/12/731836158/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/1-1.jpg/ELC5uLQIGA4gBygH/CN4xmVMBYozkdoVkY_yXluv4Yao68hgbv0V95K7Tjy4?size=2048x1536&size_mode=3" id="post1img"/>
    <p class="text-success">Bootstrap V3.3.6</p>
    <p id="post1para">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.</p>
    <div class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button Green</button></div>
  </div>
  <div id="post2" class="post">
    <img src="https://photos-3.dropbox.com/t/2/AAA0wm6tg1X1K7zHZG5l6nZGnfHWobZLJTB4L12PBjLRhQ/12/731836158/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/1-2.jpg/ELC5uLQIGA8gBygH/simGKuHsNbmiQz63msz6lnpI4VntyYBKZScXTOh08PY?size=1280x960&size_mode=3" id="post2img"/><h3 class="text-primary">Responsive Desgn</h3>
    <p id="post2para">Conquer Template is provided by templatemo for free of charge. You can use this template for any kind of website. No credit link is required. All images by Unsplash. Thank you for visiting our website. Please come again!</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button Blue</button>
  </div>
  <div id="post3" class="post">
  <img src="https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AABT_1USaAxiBj120M9ai5jS-hYbSHGkRn0yDJhQeC4rNg/12/731836158/jpeg/32x32/1/_/1/2/1-3.jpg/ELC5uLQIGA8gBygH/APtdBotAnn4vJycbaWyxY84b1TmaxKy3x2JChb8NLOE?size=1280x960&size_mode=3" id="post3img"><h3 id="post3h3">Parallax Scroll</h3>
    <p id="post3para">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">See Details </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will position the blocks according to your preferences. You can update this on your original file. See how I also add a className to your div so you can style way faster.

Comment: You could also look at vw units depeding on the browsers you need to support. Seems like a combination of fixed width to a certain media query breakpoint then switching to vw could help.

Comment: Just like @mccambridge says. It all depends on your goal of your website. % or vw units depends on your container and your preferences

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, you fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using some Bootstrap classes. Would it be easier to use the Bootstrap grid to make it easier? Maybe try using the class of `col-sm-4` for 3 columns to make it responsive. If not Bootstrap, I use 3 divs and float them to the left with a width of 33.3% or 33% if you want spacing then use a media query to break it into a 50% div and then a 100%.

Also I would try to target the same class to prevent writing repetitive CSS for those columns

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Responsive Web Design Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_grid.asp) , similar to @Trace751 suggestion of Bootstrap.